# Please can you help me with my IF statements?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Whats wrong with the following code (I think its something to do with the if statements), i've tried looking it up online, but to no success?

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="formSeven">
  <p><input type="text" name="z11" value="" size="4" /> <span> Adjusted BMI </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z12" value="" size="4" /> <span> Age in years </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z13" value="" size="4" /> <span> Male or Female </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="result7" value="" size="4" /> <span> BF% </span></p>
  <p><input onclick="calculate7()" type="BUTTON" value="Calculate" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">// 
function calculate7() {
    var x = document.formSeven.z11.value;
    var y = document.formSeven.z12.value;
    var z = document.formSeven.z13.value;
    if (z == "Female"){
        document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-5.4;
    }
    else if (z == "Male") {
        document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-16.2;
    }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Use apostrophes (`'Female'`), not curly quotes (`‘Female’`).

Comment: Also try using z.toLowerCase() in case your user doesn't use a capital letter.Then compare the lowercase version e.g "female" otherwise it could fail on case

Comment: From UX standpoint it's not a good idea to have the user type in the gender. The options should be presented in a dropdown menu or with radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

the best to input gender is to make a select, because you won't have to worry about mistake from user :

```
<select id="gender" >
<option value="0" selected="selected">Female</option>
<option value="1">Male</option>
</select>
```

then in your javascript

```
(parseInt(document.getElementById('gender').value) === 0) ? document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-5.4:document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-16.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (z == "Female")
 document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-5.4;  
else if (z == "Male")
 document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-16.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (z === "Female"){
document.formSeven.result7.value = x+y-5.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the shortest way to do what you want.
It also gives you some error margin as it is case insensitive.

```
document.formSeven.result7.value=(z.toLowerCase()=='female'?(x+y-5.4):(x+y-16.2));
```

here

```
document.formSeven.result7.value=(z.toLowerCase()=='female'?(x+y-5.4):(z.toLowerCase()=='male'?(x+y-16.2):''));
```

replace the latest z with whatever value you want.

Here is your full code:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="formSeven">
  <p><input type="text" name="z11" value="" size="4" /> <span> Adjusted BMI </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z12" value="" size="4" /> <span> Age in years </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z13" value="" size="4" /> <span> Male or Female </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="result7" value="" size="4" /> <span> BF% </span></p>
  <p><input onclick="calculate7()" type="BUTTON" value="Calculate" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">// 
function calculate7() {
  var x = document.formSeven.z11.value;
  var y = document.formSeven.z12.value;
  var z = document.formSeven.z13.value.toLowerCase();
  var r = document.formSeven.result7;
  r.value=(z=='female'?(x+y-5.4):(z=='male'?(x+y-16.2):r.value));
}
// ]]></script>
```

You can also clean up the code a little more

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="formSeven">
  <p><input type="text" name="z11" size="4" /> <span> Adjusted BMI </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z12" size="4" /> <span> Age in years </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="z13" size="4" /> <span> Male or Female </span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="result7" size="4" /> <span> BF% </span></p>
  <p><input onclick="calculate7()" type="button" value="Calculate" /></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calculate7() {
 var f=document.formSeven,
 x=f.z11.value,
 y=f.z12.value,
 z=f.z13.value.toLowerCase(),
 r=f.result7;
 r.value=(z=='female'?(x+y-5.4):(z=='male'?(x+y-16.2):r.value));
}
</script>
```

Comment: u didn't even had the time to read the code and downvoted ... explain that pls

Comment: Did you read the code in the question? User can input anything to `z13`, your code assumes everything but `Female` being `Male`. Not my downvote though.

Comment: Well, I don't need this, but now your code adds anything outside `Female` and `Male` to `result7`, in the original code there is nothing changed in that field in this case.

Comment: "replace the latest z with whatever value u want." in your case replace z with ''.

Comment: Why don't you do it, it's your answer. You might get rid of the downvote... But actually there should be `document.formSeven.result7.value`.

Comment: also added the document.formSeven.result7.value

Comment: Now it's doing the same what the original code does. But like I said, I haven't downvoted your answer, so I can't remove the downvote either.

Comment: no problem i just wanted to help and show u how to properly write short javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The values are strings, so instead of adding the numbers, you will be concatenating the strings.

Parse the strings into numbers:

```
var x = parseInt(document.formSeven.z11.value, 10);
var y = parseInt(document.formSeven.z12.value, 10);
```